# parse json and then compare with if statement not working

Tags: javascript, json

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

the json (response):

```
Response: {"success":true,"message":"Registration Success, check your email to validate your account so you can login"}
```

My code:

```
        console.log("Response: "+response);
        obj = JSON.parse(response);
alert(obj.success);
        if (obj.success == 'true')
{
        console.log("Response:success detected ");
alert('hi');

}
```

I never get inside the if statement even though alert(obj.success) gives me an alert with 'true'. what is making my if statement not function correctly?

Comment: Try `alert(obj.success == 'true');`

Comment: @PSL but the alert is working which means the parsing is fine

Comment: @ArunPJohny aah.. yeah right. i din't see that..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not `'true`', it's `true`. Remove the quotes.

In a JavaScript console:

```
'true' == true
=> false
true == true
=> true
'true' == 'true'
=> true
```

You may have thought this would be the case because in languages like PHP, `true` does indeed == `'true'`.

Comment: perfect, you appear to be 100% correct. I did not know this, thank you for such a detailed answer. will accept when times up.